# Spring Boot Maven Won't Build Executable Jar because it's finding duplicates

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

So I try to run mvn clean package to build an executable jar for my Spring Boot application, and it fails because it's finding duplicates.

Here is an example of the error message that's coming up. A majority of them seem to be Tomcat-related:

```
[WARNING] Found duplicate (but equal) classes in [org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.20, org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.5.20]:
```

Where are these duplicates coming from? Does it have anything to do with my pom.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Output to jar format -->
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starters</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Boot Web Starter</name>
    <description>Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring
        MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container
    </description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA Data (for using Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                                <mainClass>
                                    app.ContactRunner
                                </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Maybe it's because I imported too many starter projects or something? Really just not sure.

**Edit**

Ran it with a fuller stack trace, and it says I don't have any goal defined, though my POM clearly has one:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have
>   been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle
>   phase or a goal in the format : or
>   :[:]:.

But I think it's due to all the duplicate dependencies that come up. I've seen some posts on removing them, but none of them make sense, as the dependencies come in automatically through some of the larger, over-arching `<dependency>` tags

For example, one warning is saying this:

```
[WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.20, org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final]:
[WARNING]   javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
[WARNING]   javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType
```

I need both the tomcat and the jpa dependency, and I didn't specifically add the PersistenceContext, they add them automatically. How do I prevent the dependency duplication or prevent the error?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<scope>test</scope>` from this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Remove these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In summary: rely on the `spring-boot-starter-*` artifacts to provide you with the correct transitive dependencies rather than trying to add (potentially conflicting) individual Spring dependencies.

**Update 1** in response to this:

> when I get rid of those dependencies, it causes the @GetMapping or @ResponseBody annotations to not be found in the project

The `GetMapping` and `ResponseBody` interfaces are in `org.springframework:spring-web` which is provided via the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` artifact. So, as long as you have removed `<scope>test</scope>` from your `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency then you'll have these. Try rebuilding your project from the command line and/or reimporting it into your IDE **after** making the changes I suggested.

You can also remove this ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

... because it is provided by `spring-boot-starter-web`

And, if `h2` is a test-only replacement for `mysql` then you should add `<scope>test</scope>` to this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.194</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, I'd recommend using either or both of these tutorials to play around with these aspects of Spring Boot in a small-scale, safe way:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: That is eliminating some of them, I'm still having some crashes in the versions of Tomcat and Tomcat vs. Hibernate. Also, when I get rid of those dependencies, it causes the `@GetMapping` or `@ResponseBody` annotations to not be found in the project, so it's not possible to remove those dependencies. Should I keep those, but remove the starters?

Comment: Hmm.. I suppose it might be better to ask, what is happening here? Why is it an issue that there are duplicate classes? After removing those you suggest, importing the changes and attempting another `mvn clean package`, it's still throwing the duplicates. I reimported the project in my IDE - it can't find those annotations. Doing a `mvn clean install` also throws an error because of the duplicates.

Comment: It's not "an issue that there are duplicate classes" _per se_ it's more liekly to be class incompatabilities. I'd strongly suggest following the links I included; use the Spring guides to create simple, functional mini projects for yourself and then use those to bootstrap your own project(s).

Comment: I followed a few various guides of theirs (not those specifically, but ones like https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ and the starter web) to build my project - and it runs through the IDE, but I need to export the project so I can run it now. It seems it's built of several mini-modules to create my finished project, I just don't understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have no idea why this worked, but when I swapped this:

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starters</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
```

In exchange for

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
```

Between the `<parent>` tags. It solved all my problems. I was able to `mvn clean package` just fine after that.